# error when passing string to php through post method

Tags: php, arrays, string, mysqli

I'm trying to pass a string argument param in the form

```
   number,number,number.... for example 1,3,5,4,8,2
```

and split it up into an array of numbers and then carry out the checkuserbets function from the Check_Bets.php file on each of the numbers and return the results as an array. However, when I run this in a REST client, I get

```
{"error":true,"error_msg":"the response is null!"}
```

as if I didn't pass the proper parameter or didn't use the POST method. This is what I am passing : 
[image]

Check_Bets_Handler.php

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['param'])) {
    // get tag
   $param= $_POST['param'];
   $id = explode(",",$param);
   $arrlength = count($id);
    // include db handler
     require_once 'include/Check_Bets.php';


    $db = new Check_Bets();
    $response["bet"] = array();


   for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

    $result= $db->checkuserbets($id[$x]);
    array_push($response["bet"], $result);
}
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
$response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "the response is null!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Check_Bets.php

```html
<?php

class Check_Bets {
  
 

   function __construct() {

 require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
 $this->db = new DB_Connect();

 $this->db->connect();


}



function __destruct() {
   
  }

  public function checkuserbets($id) {

   $conn=mysqli_connect("****", "******", "****","****");

   $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Result FROM gamelist WHERE gid = '$id'");
 $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
     
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {

 return mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    
}
}
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: See what you get when you do a print_r for your post variables.  Put this directly under your opening PHP tag:  `print "<PRE><FONT COLOR=ORANGE>"; print_r($_POST); print "</FONT></PRE>"; exit;`

Comment: also better past the code of the form not the interface.

Comment: Have you looked in the network tab in the browser debugger to see that the variable is being passed?

Comment: @Quixrick I uploaded the result as an image to the bottom of the question

Comment: You need to add the form code, as there isn't enough information for us to help properly.

Comment: @eagle12 I uploaded the form code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just ran a test script of this and it seems to work as expected.  It seems that the problem you are having is that `if (isset($_POST['param'])) {` is not catching.  However, with the code that you screenshotted, that doesn't make sense to me.

I didn't have a database set up for this, so I had to make my own function, but here is the code that I ran and it works fine for me.

```
<?php

// SET SOME INFORMATION
$_POST = array("param" => '3,4,5,6,7,8,9');

if (isset($_POST['param'])) {

    $param = $_POST['param'];
    print '<br>PARAM: '.$param;

    $id = explode(",",$param);
    print "<pre><font color=blue>"; print_r($id); print "</font></pre>";

    $arrlength = count($id);
    // include db handler
    //require_once 'include/Check_Bets.php'; // DON'T HAVE THIS


    //$db = new Check_Bets();
    $response["bet"] = array();


    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

        //$result= $db->checkuserbets($id[$x]);
        $result= checkuserbets($id[$x]); // MADE MY OWN FUNCTION BECAUSE I DO NOT HAVE A DATABASE
        array_push($response["bet"], $result);
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "the response is null!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}

// DUMMY FUNCTION
function checkuserbets($id) {
    return $id * 5;    
}
```

This is what it returns:

```
PARAM: 3,4,5,6,7,8,9
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 8
    [6] => 9
)
{"bet":[15,20,25,30,35,40,45]}
```

So if you are getting the `$_POST['params']` back when you `print_r` them, but not in `isset`, then I have a couple more suggestions. You can try using either `empty` or not equal to nothing.

```
// CHECK TO MAKE SURE $_POST['param'] IS NOT EMPTY
if (!empty($_POST['param'])) {
```

OR

```
// CHECK TO MAKE SURE $_POST['param'] IS NOT EQUAL TO NOTHING
if ($_POST['param'] != '') {
```

Hopefully one of those two will fix it for you.

[Here is a working demo](http://codepad.org/UTS4I47k)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response, I replaced the isset with !empty and it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Check value can be passed in url.If value cannot passed in the url You did the mistake in posting the values

Comment: How do I check that? If you look at the bottom of the question you can see what the php file gets from the REST